# Ionic 2/3 - problems with *ngFor - only a few elements loading, locking phone's screen loads the rest

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ngfor

I having issues using `*ngFor` in Ionic 2. Basically, the aim is to print a lot of thumbnail images and details to the screen in a gallery style. Before loading the images I preload the page with the image name and a standard ion-icon of an image. Then it will start to load the thumbnails based on file path.

However, I'm having issues with `*ngFor` only loading say 50 ion-icon and thumbnail name at a time, for the rest to load I must lock the phones screen and unlock it again. They all pretty much load straight away - after the screen being locked for only two seconds. There's around 900+ images that are being loaded Btw. I'm also loading all the image data before attempting to display the information in the `*ngFor`. It seems more like a bug or limitation of `*ngFor`? as it loads straight away when the screen is locked.

Is there a better way of loading this many images? I really don't need an asynchronous stream between the array and images on the screen, as once it's loaded it will not change. I did try just inserting HTML elements with a for loop to the dom, but that goes against the angular way and seemed to take longer to load.

**Component HTML:**

```
<ion-content>
  <button style="height:200px;" (click)="buttonClicked()">Show images</button> 

  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      
      <ion-col col-4 *ngFor="let directory of directorySubDirectories">
          <div class="directory-folder"></div>
          <div class="item-name">{{directory.name}}</div>
      </ion-col >
    </ion-row >

    <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-4 *ngFor="let image of directoryService.getDirectoryImages()">
          <div class="image-container">
              <ion-icon name="images" class="image-icon" center></ion-icon>
          </div>
            <div class="item-name">{{image.name}}</div>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: Does directorySubDirectories come from a service call?

Comment: Yes it does as well - from a file.listdir in the service. I separated folders from the images into different arrays.

Comment: **directorySubDirectories** come from async call so have to use a async pipe `*ngFor="let directory of directorySubDirectories | async "`

Comment: not working unfortunately, getting error `Uncaught (in promise): Error: InvalidPipeArgument: for pipe 'AsyncPipe'`, when adding `directorySubDirectories | async`

Comment: I also imported the library `import { AsyncPipe } from '@angular/common` in the component.

Comment: I also tried removing the whole section for **directorySubDirectories ngfor** to see if it fixed the issue, no luck unfortunately.

Comment: Try doing ` <ion-row *ngIf="directorySubDirectories ">` above the ngFor. What this will do is wait for to be set and when set, load the data. It's a question of nanoseconds.

Comment: Using `<ion-row *ngIf="directorySubDirectories "` cause the directories not to show up at all. Doesn't fix the issues either. Thanks for the help, its much appreciated!

Comment: Ditch the space btw `<ion-row *ngIf="directorySubDirectories">`

Comment: Already did, no luck :(

Comment: Then I'm not sure either.

Comment: Thats ok, I really appreciate you time, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with *ngFor not updating when the observable returned the images details (directoryImages array) from the directoryService. To fix this I had to trigger the ngFor to recheck the array using changeDetectorRef.detectChanges().

**Steps:**

1. Import ChangeDetectorRef to the component:

   `import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';`
2. Pass a reference to the ChangeDetectorRef service in the constructor:

`constructor(private ref:ChangeDetectorRef)`

3. Trigger the *ngFor with the changeDectorRef when data has been updated from the observable

`this.directoryService.getDirectoryImages().subscribe((result)=>{
      this.directoryImages = result;
      this.ref.detectChanges();
});`